# Using token for Confluence REST API does not work

Tags: javascript, rest, confluence

Following the Atlassian documentation, I want to use token I generated for our internal, on-premise Confluence.

```js
let resp = HTTP.call('GET', url, "headers: {Authorization: Bearer "+ getToken()});
```

This always results into a message containing "authorized: false".

I tried various tips I found on the Atlassian forums: changing Bearer to basic, putting the authorization right in the body of the message, but no success.
My understanding was that all I need is to have "Authorization: Bearer ".

Answer (score 0):

I'm also having issues getting this to work, but I noticed you should be using "Basic authentication" rather than "Bearer", and just replace the previous password with the new token, keeping the same username.

I had a solution previously that authenticated (before the deprecation), which I just changed to:

```
string encodedCred = Convert.ToBase64String(Encoding.GetEncoding("ISO-8859-1").GetBytes(conflUserName + ":" + ConfluenceAPIToken ));

  request.Headers.Add("Authorization", "Basic " + encodedCred);
```

Still I don't manage to get it to work. Keen on any ideas on this.

Been trying it out with both Postman (fail) and now Curl (also fails).

Has anyone managed to do this?

Comment: My problem was that I was not using the Bearer-protocol for authentication credentials. 

This is explained in the docs here: 

  https://confluence.atlassian.com/enterprise/using-personal-access-tokens-1026032365.html.

Took me a lot of hard work reading/testing and just not giving up. One mght think that such a cricitcal detail/treshold to get going with REST APIs could have been so much easier and accessible to get hold of, a clear and fully functional sample does it all. Will try to provide one once I get to clean out one.

Answer (score 0):

Just noticed I had followed the guide on this Atlassian page:

https://support.atlassian.com/atlassian-account/docs/manage-api-tokens-for-your-atlassian-account/

which links to https://id.atlassian.com/manage-profile/security/api-tokens where I created my first tokens to play with.

And now I instead went in under Account | General Settings | Personal Access Tokens on the Confluence instance which I actually want to access, and there I don't see the previously created token. Hence I created a new token here => same problem:

curl -D- -u USERNAME:TOKEN -X GET -H "Content-Type: application/json" https://COMPANY-DOMAIN-CONFLUENCE-INSTANCE/rest/api/content/938388123

still same problem:

Basic Authentication Failure - Reason : AUTHENTICATED_FAILED

**Description** The request has not been applied because it lacks valid authentication credentials for the target resource.

#### Apache Tomcat/9.0.73

...

I have verified I use the same user name as I do on the instance I want to access, where I can log in via the browser. I have copied the password from the browsers settings. I can access the url I specify to curl.

What else could there be?

Answer (score 0):

I could have surpassed my retry count limit, but then I would not likely be able to log in to a web session without errors. I seem to be getting captchas prompts every time I log in though.